# Why are some colorings called "Fast", i.e. Fast Yellow AB (E105)?

Tags: food-chemistry

Every time I look into things like this, I keep seeing talk about "fast food logos", so I've hit a dead end.  What makes a specific color "fast"?

I see Fast Yellow and Fast Green on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_number#E100%E2%80%93E199_(colours)), but no mention of *why* it's called "fast".  Is it just a name, like how some colors are called "Brillant"?  Is it a color that looks like something frequently used on race cars or fast food, so they just call it "Fast XYZ"?

Comment: Perhaps they can be made color-fast?

Comment: Usually when dipping a fabric or a cloth into a dyeing solution, it takes a long time to have it colored. It is necessary to wait long enough for the dye to enter the inner parts of the fibres. It is not the case for the fast dyes. As soon as the fabric or the cloth is dipped into the fast coloring solution, it is perfectly colored.

Comment: [Colour fastness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_fastness)

Comment: http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/webprojects2002/price/fastness.htm

Comment: Use quotes in your google search: $$\mathrm{"fast\ blue" meaning}$$

Comment: During the search, I came across acid-fast bacteria, those that don't lose a stain when washing with acid: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30725806/

Comment: It's the same as in "Fasten your seatbelt", i.e. to make the seatbelt "fast".

Comment: @Loong that article is an example of useless Wikipedia articles: it doesn't tell whether fastness of a "fast to fade" dye is higher or lower, while it's crucial due to being counterintuitive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A good dictionary is your best friend. Fast as an adjective for a color

> Of a colour or dye: that will not readily fade or wash out; permanent. Now also in fast to: not susceptible to fading from. The usage dates to 1658!
>
> 1658   W. Sanderson Graphice 80   Fast and firm colours, as Umber,
> Oke.
>
> [Unabridged Oxford English Dictionary]

This word has a different root than your "fast" food. It is cognate with German *fest* which means firmly established.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/german-english/fest

Recall that the dye industry fluorished in Germany from coal tar.

Comment: Also compare "fasten", "fastener", expression "fast asleep". Most Germanics actually adopt a version of "fast" with this meaning as well.

Comment: Given that the term "Lake" seems to also be derived from other historical terms, I had a feeling it was some kind of reference to that, and I take it that in that case, Fast Yellow would be more permanent than other dyes that aren't Fast?  Also I completely forgot to address color fastness in my original question, as I was wondering if that's what it was about.  Thank you!